# Unable to import python module 'web'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, web.py

I am trying to import the web module of python to create a simple Hello World program on my browser using `web.py`.

When I run it from the command line I am getting errors about  the web.py package. If I run it from IDLE, it works fine.

Comment: add the error traceback

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is in the PYTHONPATH, and the IDE modify the environment variables so when you run it from there you don't have a problem.